# Javascript will not close a window (nested scripts)

Tags: javascript

I am faced with a rather irritating issue regarding JavaScript. The problem is that this is a third party code and I am not allowed/able to use this code on a public website. :-( I know that makes it much harder to troubleshoot but I hope you will bear with me.

The situation is like this:

1) `Page1` is called from any webpage to open a chat function and this consists of a JavaScript page. In this page we set a page identifier using `YYYPage thisPage = htmlcSession.guiEngine.pageManager.yyyPage;`
At the end of this page, an include to another jsp file is made.

2) Once loaded this page (as mentioned in step 1) this page opens a second page which partitions the resulting page in 5 sections (FRAMES are used here, the code has not been adapted for the past xx years)

In each of these frames different functionalities are presented and as 2 of these frames are important. The top frame, which is called a controller frame and the middle frame (called Answer frame) which eventually loads the exit page.

All these frames have "unique" names and as a result I would expect that when I end up in the exit page, I should be able to close the main window by calling `YYYPage.Close()`;

I think the question comes down to this:
Is it possible to close a parent window from within one of the child windows (when ***all*** windows have been opened by the JavaScript `window.open` command!!)?

If so, how can I refer to the correct window?

Comment: JS cannot close a window that was not itself opened via JS code.

Comment: show code and for the love of god stop calling it jsp it makes me think of JavaServer Pages :S

Comment: @Marc B, If with your comment you mean that a child page cannot close a parent page, then I have my answer. All pages are opened by using the window.open() method.

Comment: @VeXii: I would love to copy all the code in here, but I am not allowed to do so (copyright issues and so on, I am not the developer of that code, I am only in need of changing it). But they are Java Server Pages, sorry for my mistake. If this question needs to be in a different section, then I would gladly change that.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for an answer to this and ended up just figuring out a hack. I hate unanswered questions, so here's my solution: You can trick the parent window into closing itself using a set timeout. For some reason this doesn't trigger any security blocks on the script:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.top.setTimeout('window.close()',1)">Close Window</a>
```